# Use a checkbox or radio button to save search term in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable in a rails app where I am using the built in `stateSave` so that a user's choices of visible columns, column order, and search terms. I would like to have some way to force the user to choose to save the search term. So the desired function would be saving state like it does automatically, but null the search value unless the checkbox is checked. I've run into a few issues.

1. If I add a checkbox that sets the search term to the current search value, I have to either force the user to only check it AFTER they have modified the search term, or check it every time they type something into the search box.
2. I have only figured out how to turn sateSave on or off with the checkbox, not just the search function. Which will mess with their other settings that I always want saved.

I think the way to go is to have a checkbox that when checked or unchecked it fires a function that changes the jQuery stateSave param but JUST for the search function. I've spend literally many hours reading through the DataTables docs and forums but can't figure it out. It seems like it should be an easy thing to just turn one of the stateSave params on or off. Here is the javascript I have so far:

```
$('#some_table').dataTable( {
        stateSave: true,
        stateDuration: 0,
        dom: '<"toolbar">Bfrtip',
        colReorder: true,
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'colvis', position: 'dropdown', columns: ':not(.noVis)',
                className: "btn btn-xs btn-brand dropdown-toggle", dataToggle: "dropdown", ariaExpanded: "false"},
            { extend: 'copy', className: 'btn btn-xs btn-brand' },
            { extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-xs btn-brand' },
            { extend: 'csv', className: 'btn btn-xs btn-brand' },
            { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn btn-xs btn-brand' }
        ],
        inputType: 'search',
        name: 'search',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter: "
        },
        search: {
            search: '<%= raw(@filter) %>'
        },
        "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "columnDefs": [
            {"targets": [0], "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"},
            {"targets": [0], "className": "noVis"}
        ],
        scrollY:        550,
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedHeader:           {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            if (getParam() !== 'undefined') {this.api().search(getParam()).draw();}
        }
    } );
```

The `getParams` is a function that just grabs part of the url and applies it to the search box. This is for when people click on a tag link from another page to populate the search with that term. When they navigate away it will save that search term since I have stateSave set to true. If a user enters a new search filter term in the search box and then checks a checkbox, it should update the saved state with the new term automatically. I think if I can come up with a way to turn search term saving on or off through the API it should do that automatically.

I tried adding this to my table definition above:

```
        data.search.search = "";
        data.search.smart = $('#saveSearchCheckbox').prop('checked');
    },
```

and a checkbox like:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="saveSearchCheckbox">Save Search</label>
```

but it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: ***I have to either force the user to only check it AFTER they have modified the search term, or check it every time they type something into the search box*** <-- The `input` event is triggered from either of these situations.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. JS is really a weak point for me. Can you elaborate with some example of how to leverage that event?

Answer (score 0):

As you have said that you have written code for enabling/disabling the stateSave of datatable but probably you have done wrong as you have just given the datatable configuration code. so let me explain with coding example

```
var dataTableConfiguration = {
// here you can add your datatable configuration that you already mentioned above. 
};

var dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableConfiguration);

$('#yourCheckbox').change(function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    dataTable.destroy();
    dataTableOptions.stateSave = true;
    dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableOptions);
  } else {
    dataTable.destroy();
    dataTableOptions.stateSave = false; 
    dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableOptions); 
  }

});
```

The above example is for enabling/disabling the stateSave according to checkbox selection. but if you want to enable the stateSave just for search term you can modify the above code into change event of checkbox

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  dataTable.destroy();
  dataTableOptions.stateSave = true;
  // Save only the search term
  dataTableOptions.stateSaveParams = function(settings, data) {
    data.search.search = settings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch;
  };
  dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableOptions);
} else {
  dataTable.destroy();
  // Disable stateSave
  // Reset the stateSaveParams
  dataTableOptions.stateSave = false;
  dataTableOptions.stateSaveParams = null;
  dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableOptions); 
}
```

Hope this will help.

Ref: [stateSaveParams](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams)

**Updated:**

You can now add this configuration in your datatable configuration to capture the search input keyup event to save the search terms

```
var dataTableOptions = {
  // DataTables options
  "initComplete": function() {
    var searchInput = $('.dataTables_filter input');

    // Attach keyup event listener to the search input
    searchInput.on('keyup', function() {
      var searchTerm = searchInput.val();
      // Save search term to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem('searchTerm', searchTerm);
    });
  }
};

var dataTable = $('#some_table').DataTable(dataTableOptions);

// Retrieve search term from localStorage on page load
var storedSearchTerm = localStorage.getItem('searchTerm');
if (storedSearchTerm) {
  // Apply the stored search term to the DataTable search input
  $('.dataTables_filter input').val(storedSearchTerm);
  dataTable.search(storedSearchTerm).draw();
}
```

Comment: I gave the example of what I wrote in my question, the configuration is all there. Your answer does not work. I get  `uncaught TypeError: dataTable.destroy is not a function` when I click on the checkbox.
 
  Also I don't want to RESET the data table state, I want to save the search term if the box is checked and null it out if it is not. But I still want the other state params like visible columns and column order.

Comment: by the way above code is working fine, as you can check here on my codepen link -> https://codepen.io/mbt/pen/BaGpEZG

anyhow you just want to save the search term if the checkbox is enabled, so where you want to save that user searched terms on browser localStorage or in db.

Comment: You are missing the part where a requirement is to be able to use the other facets of state saving i.e. column order and column visibility. Thank you though.